# Prove that the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality holds for any list of numbers whose length is a power of 2

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I am self-studying and currently reading How to Prove it by Velleman. I tried to prove the above by induction (I proved that this holds true for $n=2$), but I think my proof is wrong. I only started reading on proofs and induction yesterday and while it makes sense on paper,it still gives me a hard time to use. So here is my proof:

$$ \frac {a_1+a_2+...+a_{2^{n+1}}}{2^{n+1}}={\frac{1}{2}\frac{a_1+a_2+...a_{2^{n}}}{2^{n}}}+\frac{a_{2^n+1}+a_{2^n+2}+...+a_{2^{n+1}}}{{2^{n+1}}}
\quad
\frac {a_1+a_2+...+a_{2^{n+1}}}{2^{n+1}} \geq \frac{1}{2} \sqrt[2^n]{a_1a_2...a_{2^n}}+\sqrt[2^{n+1}]{a_1a_2...a_{2^{n+1}}}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt[2^n]{a_1a_2...a_{2^n}}
\quad
\frac {a_1+a_2+...+a_{2^{n+1}}}{2^{n+1}} \geq \sqrt[2^{n+1}]{a_1a_2...a_{2^{n+1}}}
$$

Also sorry for any formatting mistakes, this is my first time trying Latex. This is also why the proof skips a few steps at the beginning.

Comment: How did you get the second term in the inequality from the first equation?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.I have to prove that $\frac {a_1+a_2+...+a_{2^{n}}}{2^{n}} \geq \sqrt[2^{n}]{a_1a_2...a_{2^{n}}}$ So since I proved it for $n=2$ I tried to prove it that if it holds for $n$, it must hold for $n+1$. I basically took each term seperately as inequality and then added them together to get the final result. I could probably write it a bit better if that would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only $2^n$ numbers from $2^n+1$ to $2^{n+1}$.  So the last part on the first line should be 
$$\frac12\frac{a_{2^n+1}+a_{2^n+2}+\cdots+a_{2^{n+1}}}{2^n}$$
very similar to the first part.
Then, after applying the AM-GM on each of the two parts, you will need to apply the AM-GM again to combine the two parts into one.

Comment: So we end up with: $\sqrt{\sqrt[2^{n}]{a_1a_2...a_{2^{n}}}\sqrt[2^{n}]{a_{2^{n}+1}...a_{2^{n+1}}}}$ Which gives us the result we want,right?

Comment: Yes, that's right